# Cin Ambiguity in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, namespaces, cin, cout

From past 1 week I am getting the cin and cout ambiguous error in VS Code.

At first it seems that I have imported more than one namespaces thats why the error is coming so I tried to write the most basic cpp code and still it is showing that cin and cout is ambiguous.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;cin>>n;
    cout << n;
}
```

Even this code is also showing ambiguous error when I am specifying std::cin and std::cout then it is resolved. But it is troublesome to write std:: everytime.
Can someone help?

Comment: Are the locations of the definitions listed? Is this a compiler error or is this just related to code analysis tools used by the IDE? What happens, if you replace `using namespace std;` with `using std::cin; using std::cout;`? Btw: Attempting excessively shorten the code imho isn't a good idea; the `std` namespace contains a huge number of symbols and it's easy to keep them all in mind.

Comment: Terminology: this code does **import** anything. It has a `using` declaration that tells the compiler to pretend that everything that's defined in the namespace `std` is also defined in the global namespace. That's a bad idea.

Comment: What, specifically, is the error message that you're seeing, and where is it showing up?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the unnecessary extensions ,I just had an extension name c++ coderunner or something which was causing the issue just remove the extensions and let me know if it works otherwise we will work with the formatting of launch.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).